# Java Swing Storing & Rendering Text with Tabs

Tags: java, html, swing, rtf, jeditorpane

My swing app contains a JEditorPane which lets users edit text in a WYSIWYG fashion, including toolbar buttons for bold, italic, and setting fonts, etc.

The content type on the JEditorPane is text/html

The problem: Users want to be able to type tab characters in the editor pane, close the edit dialog (saving HTML text to persistent storage) and see their tabs rendered. However, HTML treats all whitespace runs as a single space.

```
public class NoteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JEditorPane editPane1 = new JEditorPane("text/html", "Try typing some tabs");
        editPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(editPane1));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(new JEditorPane("text/html", editPane1.getText()))); // where did the tabs go?
    }
}
```

After typing tabs in the first JEditorPane, we get the HTML text from it, and pass it to a second JEditorPane, which renders the tabs as spaces.

How can I render these tabs? Should I be saving the user-entered content as RTF instead of HTML? Should I parse the HTML and build an HTML table with rows and cells (ugh). Or is there some way to tell swing to render the tab characters as tabs?

Comment: it is an HTML property though..HTML did not have _tab_ thing, even if you give multi-spaces in html, it will renders as a single white-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use < PRE > < /PRE > tags for the text and 	 for the tab char?

Comment: Thanks Stanislav, I added a stylesheet rule to the HTMLDocument to do this.

Answer (score 3):

For better help sooner, post an SSCCE.  This SSCCE does not show the behavior you describe.

[image: Text with tab included]

Note the 'tab' between the `n` & `g` of `typin  g`.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NoteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JEditorPane editPane1 = new JEditorPane("text/html", "Try typing some tabs");
        editPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(editPane1));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(new JEditorPane("text/html", editPane1.getText()))); // where did the tabs go?
    }
}
```

There were some tabs at the end that disappeared, but that makes sense, since tabs are not supported in HTML correctly unless included in a `pre` element.  I'm guessing that the Swing HTML parsing ignores them as redundant.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, so how can I render user-entered tabs as tabs (instead of spaces) after they close the initial JEditorPane in which they entered the tabs?